# Haskell, how to run this?

Tags: haskell

I have this code :

```
divideByTen :: (Floating a ) => a -> a
divideByTen = (/10)
```

If I put this into .hs file. Seems this is not enough.

(I use ghci on Mac osx).

Thank you.

After I did  :load ****.hs

I got this error

```
byby.hs:1:17:
    Class `Floating' used as a type
    In the type signature for `divideByTen':
      divideByTen :: (Floating a) a -> a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't tell us more about what you have tried and what error messages you get. On my system, the above two lines alone in a .hs file load just fine in ghci.

Comment: I think you need to add "let " to defining the function in GHCi; if I enter "let divideByTen = (/10)" it is accepted, and if I proceed with "divideByTen 20" the result is "2.0".

Comment: @asjo: this is only the case if you want to define `divideByTen` *at the GHCi prompt*. If you include this definition in a `.hs` file, as the OP seems to want to do, you cannot in fact prepend "let".

Comment: It seems you are missing a `=>`?

Comment: @macron: thanks for the clarification (the function was so short that I automatically ignored the "store in a file and read it"-part :-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you showed in the code slice is fine, but your error clearly shows you're missing a `=>` in your type signature.

In the future please copy/paste your code in question.  If you did then perhaps your editor has converted `=>` to Unicode or some other transformation.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the arrow `=>` seems to get dropped somewhere, as evidenced by the absence of this arrow in the type signature given for `divideByTen` in the error message GHC spouts back.

Make sure that the content of your .hs file matches the code snippet you gave above exactly, and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

As it's written, your code works for me.

Are you using an ide that might do odd transformations on the source code?  Go to a command line and dump the content of the file to check.

How are the lines indented?  Is there any other code in your file?  Whitespace can change how lines are parsed in Haskell.